Snipping Tool - Odd behavior in Windows 11 23H2
the tool closes any open menu drop down lists, this seems odd! If I'm after showing a 'trail' of behavior, that I need to capture!
Why?

Try performing a Reset on the application through Settings

you're not using it correctly ... set a delay in the snip tool ... that should give you enough time to open dropdowns
